Unable to save data using HasOne association in Cakephp 4
I have tried to join two tables using hasOne association in my cakephp app
There are two tables users and admin. In both tables the id is primary key. i have linked the mobile field of admin to the add users table. So by hasOne association the user added in user table is supposed to be linked to admin and get added in admin table too. But i am unable to enter the user as an error is occuring
Here is the table structures
user table
admin table

Here is the code of add page of the user template. It is the page to enter users
<?php
/**
 * @var \App\View\AppView $this
 * @var \App\Model\Entity\User $user
 */
?>
<div class="row">
    <aside class="column">
        <div class="side-nav">
            <h4 class="heading"><?= __('Actions') ?></h4>
            <?= $this->Html->link(__('List Users'), ['action' => 'index'], ['class' => 'side-nav-item']) ?>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <div class="column-responsive column-80">
        <div class="users form content">
            <?= $this->Form->create($user  , ['type'=> 'file']) ?>
            <fieldset>
                <legend><?= __('Add User') ?></legend>
                <?php
                    echo $this->Form->control('email');
                    echo $this->Form->control('password');
                    echo $this->Form->control('Re_enter_password');
                    echo $this->Form->control('admin.mobile');
                    echo $this->Form->control('image' , ['type'=> 'file']);
                ?>
            </fieldset>
            <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

This is the user file in the Entity folder.I have added the admin = true in the accessible function so that admin will be accessible by user
  protected $_accessible = [
        'email' => true,
        'password' => true,
        'created' => true,
        'modified' => true,
        'articles' => true,
        'admin' => true,
        'status' => true,
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false

    ];

This is the add function in the UserController file. It is used to add new users
public function add()
    {
        $user = $this->Users->newEmptyEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());

    
           if (!$user->getErrors) {
                $image = $this->request->getUploadedFiles();
                
               $name = $image['image']->getClientFilename();
               

         

               $targetPath = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.$name;

                if ($name) {
                   $image['image']->moveTo($targetPath);
                }

                $user->image = $name; 
            } else {
                echo "Error uploading" ;
                echo $user->getErrors;
            }


            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.')); 
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
       
    }

This is the Users table file where i have defined the HasOne relation
 public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('users');
        $this->setDisplayField('email');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasMany('Articles', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        ]);

        $this->hasOne('Admin');
    }


I think you've posted the same image for both user and admin tables. The admin table is surely different than shown, right?

Sorry , i have edited my question

I believe your admin table needs to have a user_id column, which will be the ID of the user record. You might be thinking that id will just be the same in both, but I don't think Cake works like that, at least not by default.

I have done that but it's not working. I was following the tutorial by Alimon Pito on youtube. There was a comment which said "had to add ['associated'=>['Contacts']] in usercontroller.php" but i don't understand this. I have replied to that guy too

@GregSchmidt hello it worked , i forgot to re bake my files after changing field in database. Thanks for help

I don't know what Models you developed but i assumed you don't have setted up well your database.
In order to have a hasOne association you must have an 'user_id' on the Admins table, who points at 'id' on the Users table (foreign key). On the other hand, you must have an 'admin_id' on Users table pointing to 'id' on Admins table (foreign key).
See on the documentation:
HasOne Associations CakePhp4
HasOne Associations CakePhp5
